# $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx$ if $f(1)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx$ if $f(1)=0$.

I know that if $f$ is continuous then $\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0$ by applying substitution $u=x^n$ and using the same substitution $n\times\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx \to f(1)$ as $n\to\infty$.But what happens if i still have an $n$left in the front from $n^2$ and $f(1)=0$.
My particular case is: $f(x)=(x-1)\times e^{-\frac{1}{x+5}}$. Any hints?

Comment: “if $f$ is continuous then $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx=0$” this is false, take $f(x)\equiv 1$. Do you mean “if ... then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1x^nf(x)dx=0”$?

Comment: This does not have an answer in general. Simply knowing $f(1) = 0$ is not enough to deduce the limit: if $f(x) = 0$ then the limit is $0$ and if $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ then the limit is $\pi$.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable at $x=1$ one should be able to show that the limit equals $-f'(1)$.

Comment: @Winther Okay, then I have a particular case with the function mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f \in C^1 ([0,1])$ (as in your particular case), we can integrate by parts to find
$$I_n \equiv n^2 \int \limits_0^1 x^n f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = - \frac{n^2}{n+1} \int \limits_0^1 x^{n+1} f'(x) \, \mathrm{d} x \, , \, n \in \mathbb{N} \, .$$
Then the substitution $ t = x^{n+2}$ yields
$$ I_n = -\frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \int \limits_0^1 f'\left(t^{\frac{1}{n+2}}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x \, , \, n \in \mathbb{N} \, .$$
Now the prefactor converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$ . Since $f'$ is continuous, the integrand converges to $f'(1)$ for every $t \in (0,1]$ . Since it is also bounded, we can use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = - \left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)(n+2)} \right] \int \limits_0^1  \lim_{n \to \infty} f'\left(t^{\frac{1}{n+2}}\right) \, \mathrm{d} t = - 1 \cdot \int \limits_0^1 f'(1) \, \mathrm{d} t = - f'(1) \, .  $$